# Decode JSON array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have this JSON Array in PHP which I receive from an Android request and I want to decode it so that I can get every value of each object in a loop and send them to a mysql database.

So in the example beneath, there's a class with two objects including properties FirstName and LastName. I would like to pars this json so that I can use them in a PDO function which inserts these rows in a mysql database.

```
[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
```

How do I accomplish this. After a lot of trial and error it still won't work.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
json_decode worked after all. JSON syntax issue was the problem.

Comment: I tried the json_decode. Unfortunately that didn't worked. At the end it was just a misspelled syntax issue. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I do not agree to this question being 'vague' or 'incomplete', he clearly stated that he would like to decode the json array and get each value within a loop and save them to his database.  I understood what he wanted just by reading it once.  You guys should pay more attention. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json);
var_dump($json_decoded);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Zsq1oB)